# Network Printer going to Offline

Tags: windows-7, networking, printing, printer

I have a 80 networked computer running **Windows-7**. And a **Canon LBP3310** printer attached to the system with `IP=10.0.0.12` and shared.
The problem is that sometimes,while it is online for most of other computers,  randomly going to offline for me and for some other computers and when I send a document to print, it can't to print it!

[image]

When I ping the computer that the printer attached to, I have its response successfully!

```
C:\>ping 10.0.0.12

Pinging 10.0.0.12 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.0.0.12: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.0.0.12: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.0.0.12: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.0.0.12: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 10.0.0.12:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

C:\>
```

Windows Troubleshooting also can't find origin of the problem! and the only way to get off this problem, is removing the printer and adding it again!

**What is the origin of the problem?**

Comment: Have you checked on the printer if it has a power saving feature? Try turning that off and test again.

Comment: @StBlade Shouldn't it going to offline for all the computers in the network if origin the problem was PowerSaving feature?

Comment: True. Try connecting to the web interface of the printer.  Type in the IP address of the printer into a web browser and see if there is a event viewer or error log that you can access.  The closest that I can find to it maybe going off line would be that it is cooling down the fixing unit, according to the manual page 8-54, this may trigger the windows printer driver in think that the printer has gone offline.

Comment: @StBlade Cooling down the fixing unit? What is it? and what kind of manual? page 8-54 of which manual?

Answer (score 1):

1. Click on Printers and Devices
2. Right click on the printer you're having the problem with
3. about half way down from pop up window, click on Printer Properties
4. click on the Ports tab
5. highlight the port for the printer you're working with
6. click on Configure Ports
7. uncheck the SNMP Status Enabled box
8. click ok
9. make sure there is a check in the box next to the port you for your printer
10. click on the Apply button at the bottom right
11. click ok.

Your printer should be back online

Comment: When clicking on Configure Port I got the following error: 
An error occurred during port configuration. This operation is not supported.

[OK]

Comment: Restarting the Print Spooler in Services, and deleting all the existing print jobs managed to get it working for me.